# Error with phv font family

Tags: font-encodings, fontfamily

I was just testing the template that the faculty has left me to do the work when I come across a compilation error. Debugging the code, I have come to isolate the problem, which is given by something related to the phv source but I can't identify why. According to miktex, all the necessary dependencies are installed and up-to-date so I find it quite strange to know what is wrong. I leave you the part that I have isolated and its corresponding log

```
\documentclass[spanish,12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\large \textbf{Nombre}}

\end{document}
```

Log

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+phv on input line 9.
 ("/Users/jose/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd"
File: t1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
) [1{/Users/jose/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: This message is just an information message.

Comment: Assuming that the error is later: call in the miktex console (user mode) in the tasks menu the entry to refresh the fontmaps.

Comment: You might also `\usepackage{tgheros}` and use `\sffamily`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been solved using the package you comment. A greeting !!